# Custom loss function implementation

Tags: python, keras, theano

I'm trying to implement a new loss function of my own.
When I tried to debug it (or print in it) I've noticed it is called only once at the model creating section of the code.

How can I know what y_pred and y_true contains (shapes, data etc..) if I cannot run my code into this function while fitting the model?

I wrote this loss function:

```
def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    # run over the sequence, jump by 3
    # calc the label
    # if the label incorrect punish

    y_pred = K.reshape(y_pred, (1, 88, 3))

    y_pred = K.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)

    zero_count = K.sum(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 0))
    one_count = K.sum(K.clip(y_pred, 1, 1))
    two_count = K.sum(K.clip(y_pred, 2, 2))

    zero_punish = 1 - zero_count / K.count_params(y_true)
    one_punish = 1- one_count/ K.count_params(y_true)
    two_punish = 1- two_count/ K.count_params(y_true)

    false_arr = K.not_equal(y_true, y_pred)

    mask0 = K.equal(y_true, K.zeros_like(y_pred))
    mask0_miss = K.dot(false_arr, mask0) * zero_punish

    mask1 = K.equal(y_true, K.ones_like(y_pred))
    mask1_miss = K.dot(false_arr, mask1) * one_punish

    mask2 = K.equal(y_true, K.zeros_like(y_pred)+2)
    mask2_miss = K.dot(false_arr, mask2) * two_punish

    return K.sum(mask0_miss) + K.sum(mask1_miss) + K.sum(mask2_miss)
```

It fails on:

```
theano.gof.fg.MissingInputError: A variable that is an input to the graph was 
neither provided as an input to the function nor given a value. A chain of 
variables leading from this input to an output is [/dense_1_target, Shape.0]. 
This chain may not be unique
Backtrace when the variable is created:
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: could you show the relevant malfunctioning code so we have something to go on? Your question currently is basically asking "how do I do _A_ when _B_ isn't working?" instead of "how do I get _B_ working again?"

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand that Theano is a symbolic language. For example, when we define the following loss function in Keras:

```
def myLossFn(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.abs(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

Theano is just making a symbolic rule in a computational graph, which would be executed when it gets values i.e. when you train the model with some mini-batches.

As far as your question on how to debug your model goes, you can use `theano.function` for that. Now, you want to know if your loss calculation is correct. You do the following.

You can implement the python/numpy version of your loss function. Pass two random vectors to your numpy-loss-function and get a number. To verify if theano gives nearly identical result, define something as follows.

```
import theano
from theano import tensor as T
from keras import backend as K

Y_true = T.frow('Y_true')
Y_pred = T.fcol('Y_pred')
out = K.mean(K.abs(Y_pred - Y_true), axis=-1)

f = theano.function([Y_true, Y_pred], out)

# creating some values
y_true = np.random.random((10,))
y_pred = np.random.random((10,))

numpy_loss_result = np.mean(np.abs(y_true-y_pred))
theano_loss_result = f(y_true, y_pred)

# check if both are close enough
print numpy_loss_result-theano_loss_result # should be less than 1e-5
```

Basically, `theano.function` is a way to put values and evaluate those symbolic expressions. I hope this helps.

Comment: My problem is when I run the fitting, the loss functions doesn't called - or can't I see it?

Comment: You cannot see it. Maybe there is another way to debug while running fit function but I prefer my way that I told above. Alternatively, you can run `train_on_batch()` and use my method to debug each batch.

Comment: ok..that's kinda odd that's there is no nice way to do that..><